# Explicit advise to comment on downvotes, but not for upvotes for lower rep users?

Tags: discussion, voting, popups

As asked in the title, lower rep users (I don't actually know the considered trusted rep count that makes this disappear) are explicitly advised with a pop-up to leave a comment when downvoting a question, but not if an upvote is placed.

I've often reviewed questions, where upvotes were absolutely inadequate and seemingly more coming from a sentiment for new users, instead of judging the post contents, and how it fits for particular site's policies.

It seems for many cases we hit robo upvoters at the same rate as robo downvoters. As well both of these actions are considered important for the overall health of the system, and are already explained well with the reasonings appearing from the tooltip message given on both of these buttons.

So why do we have this kind of irrational imbalance of pop-up messages actually?

Comment: So I should consider the actual downvote here as a sample or what?

Comment: The imbalance probably exist because vote up privilege is reached at 15 rep while vote down is reached at 125.

Comment: Get a room, you two! ;-)

Comment: @rene No, I'm frickin' serious ;o) ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jon Skeet doesn't want a comment notification every other minute, 24/7/52.

Comment: @Mysticial Noone asked about comment notifications here, but the pop-up appearing on downvotes for lower rep users.

Comment: If you want a pop-up asking a low-rep user to comment on upvotes, then presumably some of the low-rep users are going to comment on the upvotes. Which would be inbox spam for Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Mysticial Well, I'm more going into the opposite direction, because I think the pop-up for downvoting seems arguable IMHO.

Comment: Me every day:  "***WHO THE F^@& UPVOTED THIS S#*$????***"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downvotes are sometimes paired with comments because downvotes are often used on content that could be improved. Maybe it's a one-line answer. That's perfectly valid downvote fodder, but posting a comment to add details (particularly specifying which details are needed) is also useful. Of course, there are plenty of cases when a downvote says all that needs to be said, but new users may need to be informed that specifying what's wrong explicitly is also helpful.

By contrast, upvotes rarely need an explanation. What would you say with most upvotes? "+1: I agree" is pointless noise, as is "good question" or whatever. So new users don't need to be told to comment with their upvotes.

---

When I say "explanation", I'm talking about explaining why the vote is there, in an attempt to help improve the question/answer. I am not talking about an "explanation" that exists to *justify* your vote.

Each vote belongs entirely to the person who made it, and (outside of explicit vandalism), you should never feel that a person must *justify their vote* to you. If you believe that someone has upvoted a question/answer not in line with this site's policies, that their reason for doing so doesn't fit with your particular vision of Stack Exchange... *deal with it*.

You do not have the right to insist that someone justify themselves.

Comment: _"By contrast, upvotes rarely need an explanation."_ That's not entirely true, I've seen a lot of upvotes for questions that were just not in line with their site's policies and should require an explanation, no matter how hard it is to give one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: See my edits.

Comment: _"You do not have the right to insist that someone justify themselves."_ Sure, I know that and don't bother actually. But the site itself insists doing so, that's what my question is about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Please read what I said. The reason to ask people to explain downvotes is to get them in the habit of posting comments that can be used to improve questions/answers. The person doesn't even have to say that they downvoted. This suggestion is *not* so that you can read the comment and decide if their vote was a good vote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To summarize Nicol's answer: downvotes are a suggestion to *change the post*, and comments are an opportunity to outline *what needs changing*. Upvotes, by contrast, are votes to *keep the post the way it is*; nothing is being suggested, so no comment is needed.

Comment: @DanBron Well, for some posts there's actually a comment needed why these were upvoted. The system cannot detect this from quality of the post either way. But I agree that's a valid point.